# PhoneGap ondeviceready not called when loadUrl with Android

Tags: android, cordova

`index.html` is loaded in MainAction.

There's a link in `index.html` that will go to `game.html`. Because I need `index.html` and `game.html` to both **use landscape screen**, I can't use something like `<a href="game.html">` in `index.html`. Otherwise, only `index.html` will use landscapre and `game.html` will use screen decided by device direction, which is no expected. So that I created a class in Java to control loading web page:

```
public class JsHelper {
    private MainActivity activity;

    public JsHelper(MainActivity act) {
        activity = act;
    }

    public void goToHtml(String url) {
        activity.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/" + url);
    }
}
```

And in `index.html`, I call this to go to `game.html`:

```
window.JsHelper.goToHtml("game.html");
```

**This is the only way I can make `game.html` to use landscape screen**.

But here's the question.

If `document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, true);` is in `index.html`, `init()` will be called once.

But if it is in `game.html`, `init()` will never be called, even if there's no `document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, true);` in `index.html`.

game.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
}

function init() {
    alert("init");
}
```

And things in API will not work. `navigator.accelerometer` will be null.

I want to use `navigator.accelerometer` and make sure `game.html` use landscape.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I cant see why you don`t fire a "deviceReady" Event on the game.html site, too. You just need to add cordova.js with a script tag and it will fire.

```
function ondeviceready(){

     //Call Cordova Functions here
}
```

Comment: I did so, but it is not called at all.

Comment: sorry I can`t help you. The only reason why Cordova wouldnt fire it`s deviceready is either because the document.ready of jQuery is not firing or the cordova.js is not included in the HTML File. Can you open Game.html in Firefox or Chrome and check if cordova.js and jQuery.js is loaded properly?